# Calculate a point which is perpendicular to a line

Tags: java, javascript

I have two points store in two variable, which forms a line. I want to find a point which is perpendicular to that line from one end point in that line.

Suppose I have two points P1(x1,y1) and P2(x2,y2) then i want to find a third point P3 such that line(P1-P2) is perpendicular to line(P2,P3) and intersect at P2.

Comment: There should be some more constraints (at least one more like the distance from P1P2) because the conditions you've mentioned works for any point lying on a line perpendicular to P1P2 and going through P2.

Comment: The distance between the perpendicular point and the line, is it arbitrary chosen?

Comment: Did you find the solution here?

Answer (score 6):

First, the angle:

```
public static double angle (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double xdiff = x1 - x2;
    double ydiff = y1 - y2;
    //double tan = xdiff / ydiff;
    double atan = Math.atan2(ydiff, xdiff);
    return atan;
}
```

To get the perpendicular, you must add PI/2 to the angle of the line defined by your two points.

Once you have that angle, the formula is:

```
x = interceptPt.x + sin(perp_angle) * distance;
y = interceptPt.y + cos(perp_angle) * distance;
```

Comment: Can you please detail a bit more who are the variables involved in the formula? It is not very clear what do you mean by "the angle of the line defined by your two points".

Comment: point 1 is defined by the point coordinates (x1, y1), and point 2 is defined by the point coordinates (x2, y2). Together, point 1 and point 2 can be interpreted as points of a line

Comment: Hello, to make it work i had to use cos for x and sin for y

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Java I can recommend to use [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). Create a [LineSegment](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/LineSegment.html) and use the pointAlongOffset method. Given Points p1 and p2 the code would look like that:

```
// create LineSegment
LineSegment ls = new LineSegment(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
// perpendicular distance to line
double offsetDistance = 10;
// calculate Point right to start point
Coordinate startRight = ls.pointAlongOffset(0, offsetDistance);
// calculate Point left to start point
Coordinate startLeft = ls.pointAlongOffset(0, -offsetDistance);
// calculate Point right to end point
Coordinate endRight = ls.pointAlongOffset(1, offsetDistance);
// calculate Point left to end point
Coordinate endLeft = ls.pointAlongOffset(1, -offsetDistance);
```

Answer (score 1):

ControlAltDel is already answered but he did a mistake, replaced cos to sin

```java
x = interceptPt.x + cos(angle + 90) * distance;

y = interceptPt.y + sin(angle + 90) * distance;
```

x,y is point away from (interceptPt.x,interceptPt.y) at (distance) .

(interceptPt.x,interceptPt.y) is point in your line where perpendicular start to drawn.

angle = your line angle with horizontal axis

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer at http://jsfiddle.net/eLxcB/2/

```
// Start and end point
var startX = 120
var startY = 150
var endX = 180
var endY = 130
R.circle(startX,startY,2);

// Calculate how far above or below the control point should be
var centrePointX = startX
var centrePointY = startY;

// Calculate slopes and Y intersects
var lineSlope = (endY - startY) / (endX - startX);
var perpendicularSlope = -1 / lineSlope;
var yIntersect = centrePointY - (centrePointX * perpendicularSlope);

// Draw a line between the two original points
R.path('M '+startX+' '+startY+', L '+endX+' '+endY);

// Plot some test points to show the perpendicular line has been found
R.circle(100, (perpendicularSlope * 100) + yIntersect, 2);
```

Comment: Just got an example ans so i converted it to Java Program. But i shared the raw example with few changes

Answer (score 0):

You can store your points in `vec2d`, then use some mathematical equations to get the perpendicular point.

```
vec2d getPerpendicularPoint(vec2d A, vec2d B, float distance)
{
   vec2d M = (A + B) / 2;
   vec2d p = A - B;
   vec2d n = (-p.y, p.x);
   int norm_length = sqrt((n.x * n.x) + (n.y * n.y));
   n.x /= norm_length;
   n.y /= norm_length;
   return (M + (distance * n));
}
```