# How to draw a perpendicular line from the terminal point of another line in python?

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw a line segment orthogonal/perpendicular to the current line segment from the terminal point for a given length, here's an illustration to help better explain the problem:

[image: Sample]

Given the `line a` coordinates and an arbitrary `length`, I'd like to find the coordinates for line segment `b` and `(x3,y3)`.

Appreciate any help.

UPDATE: Found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456539/14503195) and adapted it to Python, mods please mark this as duplicate and close it.

Answer (score 4):

I think, it would be easy to use sympy module and get it.

```
import sympy.geometry as gm
line1=gm.Line(gm.Point(1,2),gm.Point(5,4))
line2=line1.perpendicular_line(line1.p2)
```

line1 - is the initial line ( equation-  -2*x + 4*y - 6)
line2- is the perpendicular line drawn at the endpoint (5,4) (equation -  -4*x - 2*y + 28)

Pleas have a look at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html for line segments in detail.

Comment: I'd like to delete this question since it was a duplicate, would appreciate if you deleted your answer so that I can delete the question. Thank you.